# installing node.js Error- throw new assert.AssertionError

Tags: node.js

I am installing node.js,

on Ubuntu 12.04,
using source node-v0.8.21.tar.gz

I am using [link](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/11/16/diving-into-node-js-introduction-and-installation/)

while `make test`,i get errors

```
python tools/test.py --mode=release simple message
=== release test-http-dns-fail ===                                        
Path: simple/test-http-dns-fail
assert.js:102
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: false == true
    at process.<anonymous> (/home/trendwise/Downloads/node.js/node-v0.8.21/test/simple/test-http-dns-fail.js:60:10)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
    at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:893:19)
    at listen (net.js:937:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:994:9)
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
Command: out/Release/node /home/trendwise/Downloads/node.js/node-v0.8.21/test/simple/test-net-pingpong.js
[02:14|% 100|+ 465|-   2]: Done                                                
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a known issue, mentioned here: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4672

I think you'll need Node 0.9 if you want it fixed, or just ignore it.